# In bot builder dialog after successful login, login_step function is not getting called

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams

Github issues for Python /[Microsoft Bot Builder]](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/46.teams-auth)/ [Python]

```
Sample information
Sample type: [Microsoft Bot Builder]
Sample language: [Python]
Sample name: <46.teams-auth>
```

We are facing an issue after successful login to the team's bot. The issue is like in teams auth bot it's asking for the login through the sign-in button and on click of it, it opens the pop-up and gets the users details and gets successful login but gives the error "botbuilder/dialogs/prompts/oauth_prompt.py init() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

This login was working fine a few days back. But even if we are trying to run the official solution given on-site it's not calling to login_step function. and directly sending the error from python packages.

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

download https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/46.teams-auth this sample
change the config.py file and put the APP_ID, APP_PASSWORD and CONNECTION_NAME
create virtual env of any python version either 3.6, or 3.7 or 3.8
Install the requirenment.txt file
run the code "python app.py"
start the MS bot emulator of version 4.12 or 4.8 also tried 4.4
connect to ng rock in settings
click on the open bot and enter http://localhost:3978/api/messages
send some messages to get the sign-in button
Click on sign in and then after successful sign in it does not go to login_step in the local emulator and when we deploy to teams bot service it gives the above error.
Expected behavior
After login, it should go to login_step in the main_dialog.py file and execute further code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. It can be followed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/issues/1797).